# How to count a swap characters between two columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                      "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
             col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                      "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

what I want is to have like this

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                      "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
             col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                      "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
             col3 = c("1","0","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","0","1","1","1","0","0"))
```

In col3, it counts the duplicated characters as 1 and unique as 0. row 6 is considered a duplicate because the swap characters ("B", "A") were counted already in row2 as unique ("A", "B"). I can easily do this in excel using the if and countif function. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pmin` and `pmax` to sort the values from left to right by rows and apply `duplicated` to check the duplicates

```
transform(
  df,
  col3 = +(duplicated(paste(pmin(col1, col2), pmax(col1, col2))) | col1 == col2)
)
```

which gives

```
   col1 col2 col3
1     A    A    1
2     A    B    0
3     A    C    0
4     A    D    0
5     A    E    0
6     B    A    1
7     B    B    1
8     B    C    0
9     B    D    0
10    B    E    0
11    C    A    1
12    C    B    1
13    C    C    1
14    C    D    0
15    C    E    0
```

Comment: Wow! This one is working without any problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option where we look for any duplicates or where `col1` and `col2` are the same. The `+` returns a binary for the logical.

```
df$col3 <- +(duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))) | df$col1 == df$col2)
```

**Output**

```
   col1 col2 col3
1     A    A    1
2     A    B    0
3     A    C    0
4     A    D    0
5     A    E    0
6     B    A    1
7     B    B    1
8     B    C    0
9     B    D    0
10    B    E    0
11    C    A    1
12    C    B    1
13    C    C    1
14    C    D    0
15    C    E    0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. If 0 is for duplicates then row 6 should be "0" because it should account for the unique values as well. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @CharlesM Oh okay, I get it now. I thought you were looking for duplicate rows, despite the order. But I've updated my answer and should be correct now.

Comment: There was an error when using my dataset - "Error: dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [6006]" but I checked the col1 and col2 lengths and they are the same.

Comment: @CharlesM I'm really not sure, as I'm not able to replicate that error at all. I tested this on an increased sample size, but it still works fine. (Ex: `set.seed(123); df1 <- data.frame(col1 = replicate(6000, sample(LETTERS[1:5], 1)), col2 = replicate(6000, sample(LETTERS[1:5], 1)))`).

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df %>% mutate(col4 = str_c(col1, col2)) %>% 
   mutate(col5 = lapply(col4, function(x) paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, ''))), collapse = ''))) %>% 
         mutate(col3 = +(duplicated(col5) | (col1 == col2))) %>% 
           select(col1, col2, col3)
   col1 col2 col3
1     A    A    1
2     A    B    0
3     A    C    0
4     A    D    0
5     A    E    0
6     B    A    1
7     B    B    1
8     B    C    0
9     B    D    0
10    B    E    0
11    C    A    1
12    C    B    1
13    C    C    1
14    C    D    0
15    C    E    0
```

Comment: It is not working as it reduces the total unique answer to my dataset

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
column <- grepl("^[.0-9]+$", dat[,1])
column

dat2 <- data.frame(Sex = dat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)),1+column)], Length = 
dat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)),2-column)])
dat2$Length <- as.numeric(dat2$Length)
dat2
```